# Datatables feature not showing just data in table is shwoing in apostrophecms

Tags: javascript, jquery, apostrophe-cms

I want to add Datatable in apostropheCMS but its feature is not showing. I have write code of datatable in index.html and added cdn of datatables and function in header file. but it does not work. Only data is display but not table.

app/lib/module/.../views/index.html

/app/view/header.html

index.html

```
{% block main %}
    <main>
       <table id="example" class="display cell-border" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                    <th>Column 4</th>
                    <th>Column 5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>System Architect</td>
                  <td>Edinburgh</td>
                  <td>61</td>
                  <td>2011/04/25</td>
                  <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

header.html

```
<header>
<script>
          $(document).ready(function() { alert();
                var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                  "pagingType": "full_numbers"
               } );
              $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
                  if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
                      $(this).removeClass('selected');
                  }
                  else {
                      table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                      $(this).addClass('selected');
                  }
              } );


          } );
       </script>
</header>
```

Comment: Why are you putting your script in /app/view/header.html? Are you referencing that file in one of your Apostrophe modules? It sounds like you see the table in your index.html file, but the $().DataTable isn't running on it - is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Joseph. yes header file is included in index.html.
in index.html like this. {% extends "layout.html" %}
and in layout.html {% import 'header.html' as header %}